# Using require.js dependency injection

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, dependencies, requirejs, require

I am trying to make a module that uses jQuery and Handlebars

This is the main file:

```
require(['app', 'jquery', 'handlebars' ], function (app, $, handlebars) {

    console.log('Running jQuery %s', $().jquery);
});
```

And this is the app file:

```
define(['jquery', 'handlebars'], function ($, hb) {

    $(function() {

        var source   = $("#some-template").html();
        var template = hb.compile(source);
        var data = {...});
});
```

Why is does it say `hb is not defined` but when I remove all dependencies it works when using `Handlebars` instead of `hb` (which is the normal way)?

Comment: Note: it's unnecessary (and generally confusing) to include dependencies for modules which are not used and are only needed by sub-modules; in your case main doesn't need handlebars (and jQuery is there only for debugging, right?) so it should not be listed in the define call.

Comment: @kryger What do you mean not used? bot jquery and handlebars are used inside the module, unless I confuse the terms here?

Comment: @kryger I am new to require.js, so what would be the right way to do it?

Comment: The signature of your "main" file should be `require(['app', 'jquery' ], function (app, $) (...)` if you're not using Handlebars in that particular module.

Answer (score 2):

Handlebars is not AMD/RequireJS compliant. You will need to `shim` it: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

```
  shim: {
    handlebars: {
      exports: 'Handlebars'
    },
  }
```